# $df(p)$ and $Df(p)$

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms

This is from Calculus in Manifold by Michael Spivak Chapter 4 Integration on Chains.
If $f:\mathbf R^n \to \mathbf R$ is differentiable, then $Df(p)\in \wedge^1(\mathbf R^n)$. By a 
minor modification we therefore obtain a 1-form $df$, defined by 
$df(p)(v_p) = Df(p)(v)$. 
Let us consider in particular the 1-forms $d\pi^i$. It is customary 
to let $x^i$ denote the function $\pi^i$ (on $\mathbf R^3$ we often denote 
$x^1$, $x^2$ and $x^3$ by $x$, $y$, and $z$). This standard notation has 
obvious disadvantages but it allows many classical results 
to be expressed by formulas of equally classical appearance. Since $dx^i(p)(v_p) = d\pi^i(p)(v_p) = D\pi^i(p)(v) = v^i$, we see that 
$dx^1(p), \ldots,dx^n(p)$ is just the dual basis to $(e_1)_p, \ldots ,(e_n)_p$. 
Thus every $k$-form $\omega$ can be written as
$$
\omega=\sum_{i_1<\ldots<i_k} \omega_{i_1\ldots\, i_k}dx^{i_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge dx^{i_k}.
$$ 
Spivak defines $df=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}dx^i$ and 
defines $Df(p)$ as derivative of $f$ at $p$.
My question is what is the difference in $df(p)$ and $Df(p)$? And why will $Df(p)\in \wedge^1(\mathbf R^n)$?

Comment: So what I can make out of this, is that with $Df(p)$ the classic notation of a differential is meant, correct? In that sense any differential (for this types of gradient functions) takes a point or vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now, the key point as I see it is that a 1-form doesn't eat a point in the manifold (here $\mathbb{R}^n$) but a tagent vector a point $p$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now, since here all of these are isomorphic, one can identify the point or vector $v$ with the tangent vector $v_p$. In that sense, yes the (classical) differential (from vector calculus) could be viewed as a 1 form.

Comment: But being belong to $\wedge^1(R^n)$,it should be alternating,means $Df(p)(v_1,...v_i,..v_j,...v_n)=-Df(p)(v_1,...v_j,..v_i,...v_n)$.how this should be true?We didn't defined Df(p)?

Comment: But it is a 1-form. So there is just one input?

Comment: ok so this should be just $Df(p)(v),v\in R^n$?

Comment: Yes. Did this answer your question? Or anything else unclear? Please don't hestiate to ask further question as I know that this stuff can be confusing in the beginning.

Comment: But still i am confused why it is alternating?I mean, In case $\omega:R^n->R$ if $\omega(v_1,..v_i,..v_j,...v_n)= -\omega(v_1,..v_j,..v_i,...v_n)$,then only we conclude $\omega$ is alternating.So how we conclude Df(p) is alternating here?please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: $\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$ I think you confusing certain things. A differential 1-form $\omega$ is not(!) a map from $\R^n \to \R$ but a map from $T_p\R^n \to \R$. Now, why is this imporant? Because then then map becomes simpily $T_p\R^n \ni v \mapsto \omega(v)$. You see, that there is just one (!) input (that is why it is called a 1-form). And any 1-form is alternating by default.

Comment: They mean the same thing, when applied to functions. Both $df$ and $Df$ at the point $p$ denote the linearization of $f$ at $p$. More specifically, given any tangent vector $v \in T_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, both $df_p(v)$ and $D_vf(p)$ are two different notations for the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction $v$.

Comment: Yes, just note that $\Lambda^1(\mathbf R^n)$ is the vector space of linear maps $\mathbf R^n\to\mathbf R$.